# What privileges does a user need to upload/deploy to every repository hosted on local Sonatype Nexus 3.0 server?

Tags: maven, nexus

Note: since I'm the only one searching for it it feels like I want to use bad practice.

I want to create a deploy-user. Its only purpose is to be configured in the settings.xml as a server-entity:

```
<servers>
 <server>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <username>deploy-user</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
 </server>
</servers>
```

The user only needs permission to upload artifacts to all the repositories hosted on the Nexus 3.0 server. I've created a role "Deployment" and need to know which privileges need to be applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the minimal set of privileges required to deploy artifacts to Nexus 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966763/what-are-the-minimal-set-of-privileges-required-to-deploy-artifacts-to-nexus-3)

Comment: Flagged as dup. Although formulated before http://stackoverflow.com/q/40966763/413020, the later one has a working solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Nexus 3

With Nexus `3.15.2-01`, I could successfully deploy a maven site with a user that had a role with the following Privileges:

- `nx-repository-view-<RepoType>-<RepoName>-add` and
- `nx-repository-view-<RepoType>-<RepoName>-edit`

e.g. `nx-repository-view-raw-Cloudogu-Docs-add`.

See [cloudogu/continuous-delivery-slides-example](https://github.com/cloudogu/continuous-delivery-slides-example/) for an example.

A good exmplanation of `nx-repository-view` vs `nx-repository-admin` can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022951/1845976).

[image]

Comment: also it should have `nx-repository-view-<RepoType>-<RepoName>-read` permission anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

#### Nexus 2

The User must have `Artifact Upload` privilege, which can be searched in `privileges` tab.

- Create a custom `Role` for your user, add `Artifact Upload` privilege to the Role.
- Bind the Role to your user.

Below is an example of `nexus 2.x`:
[image]

And this is for `nexus 3.x`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For nexus 3.x, create a new role (e.g. "deploy") and assign it the add, edit and read permissions (`nx-repository-view-<repo_type>-<repo_name>-add/edit/read`).

This suffices for maven; other clients may need more privileges.

Answer (score -1):

Recently edited on Aug-26...

Steps required for uploading to Nexus server.

1. First create a custom deployment role.
2. Then add these privileges Nexus deployment role , All Repositories -create , All Repositories -read, All Repositories -view, All Repositories -update to custom role you have created.
3. Then assign this custom deployment role to the users who ever requires upload/deploy artifacts to Nexus.