# What is the minimal set of privileges required to deploy artifacts to Nexus 3?

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus, nexus3

I'm using Nexus Repository Manager 3.1.0-04, and I want to create a user to just have deployment permissions. What are the minimal set of privileges required for that?

Right now I created a role `nx-deploy` with the following privileges:

- nx-repository-admin-*-*-read
- nx-repository-admin-*-*-browse
- nx-repository-admin-*-*-delete
- nx-repository-admin-*-*-edit
- nx-repository-admin-*-*-add

Then I created a user `deployment` with the role `nx-deploy`. I can deploy artifacts now, however, I believe I am giving too much privileges? The `admin` part is not what I want the deployment user to be, so that part has me a bit nervous.

Needless to say, there are just too many privileges to choose from under the security section.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The general rule is `nx-repository-admin` privileges are for administering the repositories and their details; `nx-repository-view` privileges are for use of the repositories once set up. Assign the latter.

To tweak repository privileges of your Deployment user(s) you should use the `nx-repository-view-*-*-*` as the assigned privilege, instead of `nx-repository-admin`. So, remove all the privileges you addressed in your question, and replace the ‘Given’ field with `nx-repository-view-*-*-*`. Since the privilege is denoted with asterisks, your Deployment users can perform all the above actions (i.e. browse, read, edit, add, and delete).

See the screenshot for reference:

[Configuring the `nx-deploy` Privilege for the `Deployment` Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gnAf.png)

You can read more about Privileges in the Security chapter: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/security/privileges

Comment: The minimal set of privileges I had to set to deploy an artifact consist of: `nx-repository-view-*-*-{edit,read,add,browse}`. I'm using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.2.1-01

Comment: Side notes: [1] The `nx-repository-view-*-*-*` privilege allows user to upload artifacts, but does NOT show UPLOAD option on the Nexus UI [2] For deployment user, consider adding `browse`, `read`, `edit`, `add` privileges separately and preferably, do NOT add the `delete` privilege.

Comment: in Nexus 3.14 to be able to upload components (upload button) your deployment user should have the nx-component-upload privilege beside the nx-repository-view-\*-\*-\*  , see documentation here https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/user-interface/uploading-components

Comment: In version 3.18.0-01 privileges read and edit are enough (just like Ben mentioned in the not accepted answer) to deploy via CI/CD (Maven) provided by GitLab.

Answer (score 10):

If you need *minimal* privileges to just deploy artifacts, `nx-repository-view-*-*-edit` is enough.

`nx-repository-admin` is used for administration and configuration

> Repository Admin
>
> These are privileges related to the administration and configuration of a specific repository

and edit is enough to modify repository content

> edit
>
> This action allows privileges to modify associated scripts, repository content, and repository administration.

BTW, you need `nx-component-upload` to upload components in web UI.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/user-interface/uploading-components

Comment: Your post does not include any explanation, instead there is only an *is enough, I think*. That makes it a comment... You can still add information about why your line of code solves the problem. Your post will be removed if some others flag it as a comment, too.

Answer (score 6):

Successful deployment by maven 3 with Nexus 3.8.0 the following rights are required

```
nx-repository-view-*-*-edit
nx-repository-view-*-*-read
```

Comment: Maven reads the repository before deployment. For this reason, the read role must be assigned.

Comment: In addition the `nx-component-upload` priv is required if the user should be allowed to perform the upload operation from the Nexus UI. But in general we want to encourage that artefacts are created by CI pipelines, not from random developer's workstation. So you may want to leave that priv out of the equation. :-)

Comment: Explanation :Why the `edit` priv and not the `add` priv ?  Because a Maven client actually performs a HTTP `PUT` when uploading artifacts, not `POST`. The Nexus `edit`  priv corresponds to being able to perform `PUT` while the Nexus `add`priv corresponds to be able to perform `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

```
nx-repository-view-maven2-maven-snapshots-edit
nx-repository-view-maven2-maven-snapshots-read
```

"maven2"is recipe,"maven-snapshots" is your repository name.